# tableView is nil when calling function from XIB

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, xib

I have a tableView that is working correctly. Contents are populated correctly. I also have couple of buttons in the navigation bar to filter content of the tableView and reloadData too. Everything is fine.

But now I'm trying to have a custom tableview header, to have some buttons in there. I created a XIB file and added it to tableview header.

**MainViewController.swft**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {       
    var headerxib:UIView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("headerView", owner: self, options: nil).first as UIView        
    var tableheader = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 80)) 
    tableHeader.addSubview(headerxib)
    return tableHeader        
}

// This is the function that I'm trying to run
func justReload(){
    println("reload \(tableView)")            
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Everything is fine so far. Then I created IBAction in my XIB swift file to call a function from the main view controller (which is the one with the tableview)

**headerView.xib**

```
@IBAction func touhcbb(sender: AnyObject) {
   let vc = MainViewController()        
   vc.justReload()               
}
```

So, here is the problem. The println() in justReload() function shows that the tableView is nil. causing error in the reloadData().

Why is it nil if the function is called from the external XIB file?

When i try to call the function from an IBOutlet in the same ViewController, everything works fine.

I appreciate if anyone have any hints or clues to point me to the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: try self.tableView.reloadData()

Comment: @derdida tried that as well. still nil

Comment: Are you creating a new MainViewController in your action function? That will not be the view controller which has the table view.

Comment: @Swipesight can u explain more? What is the right way to call an existing function in the MainViewController from the XIB swift file? (My tableView is in the MainViewController)

Comment: @Swipesight erm I cant do that, because that action method is inside another file. I updated my question to explain it better. but anyhow, if i `println(vc.tableView)` in the action method, it is also nil.

Comment: @Swipesight I'm not sure if I understand the whole flow. Sorry. Can u explain in a bit of code?

Comment: @Swipesight I found the solution. Not sure if it's what you're trying to tell me, but i need to set `headerxib.vc = self` after loading the Nib. I will post a complete answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figured out the fix for this.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {              
    var headerxib: tableHeaderView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("headerView", owner: self, options: nil).first as tableHeaderView   

    //Need this to send reference of MainViewController to the XIB's vc
    headerxib.vc = self     

    var tableheader = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 80)) 
    tableHeader.addSubview(headerxib)
    return tableHeader        
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Open your xib, and set the Class of the File's Owner to MainViewController:
[image]

**MainViewContrtoller.swift**

```
class MainViewController: UITableViewController {
    // Use IB to connect the button to this action method.
    @IBAction func touhcbb(sender: AnyObject) {
        justReload()
    }

    func justReload(){
        println("reload \(tableView)")            
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        var headerxib:UIView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("headerView", owner: self, options: nil).first as UIView

        var tableheader = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 80)) 
        tableHeader.addSubview(headerxib)

        return tableHeader
    }
}
```